# Is it okay to ask for a big-list of answers for many other (very similar) questions which are already answered?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I’m planning on asking a big-list CW-question asking for examples of useful homeomorphisms between cones, cylinders, suspensions, spheres and balls etc. together with a proof for them.

When writing the question, I noticed that *a lot* of such questions are contained in the list of *similar questions* (such as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/177536/prove-that-the-cone-over-s1-is-homeomorphic-to-d2)) together with answers and now I feel (even more) uncertain about asking the question.

> So bascially, I want to ask a big-list question aiming at creating a large collection of answers to similar-type questions most of which have (probably) already been asked. Is that okay?

For three reasons I still feel like asking the question:

- It’s a lot of work to dig through all these already-answered questions and it would certainly be nicer to have an array of the more useful ones together at one place.
- It gives the chance to share an answer to a useful question *that hasn’t been asked yet*. (I can imagine someoone going “Oh, yeah: I use this homeomorphism all the time which noone else seems to use – it makes my life way easier.”)
- Over time, the answers will probably be sorted less by the *elegance* of their arguments, but rather by the *usefulness* of their statements (which is nice for a change).

So should I go on asking the question or not?

---

To address the concern of this specific question being too broad raised by GrigoryM, here’s the question I was going to ask in its raw form:

> This is about collecting a *big list* of useful homeomorphisms between
>
> - cones, mapping cylinders, suspensions and quotients
> - of spheres $S^n$, disks $D^n$ and euclidian spaces $E^n$ (where $E^n \cong \mathbf R^n$)
> - using (obvious) inclusions, projections, embeddings etc.
>
> **backed up by a proof**. For example, why is
>
> - $S^n \cong ΣS^{n-1}$,
> - $\operatorname{cone}S^n \cong D^n$, or
> - $D^n/S^{n-1} \cong S^n$?
>
> In Bredon’s *Topology and Geometry*, examples 13.9 and 13.10 demonstrate techniques to prove such homeomorphisms, and I would like to see more of those.

Comment: A simple question: Does a downvote on this mean “bad meta question” or “No, it’s not okay.”?

Comment: I would guess the latter.

Answer (score 4):

As you propose it, I think it is too broad. But if the point is to get that content on MSE, you can ask (and answer) a separate question for each problem and link all of them. This gets the job done and circumvents its large broadness.

I would like it if someone did this.

Comment: I strongly suspect each of 3 questions mentioned in the update has already been asked (e.g. [suspension of sphere](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/119777/)...).

Comment: Okay, as a side project, I will now collect all the questions and answers of this kind, and work through them. Then I will see what I do with them. Maybe I will put them on my blog as mrf suggested.

Answer (score 3):

To me it sounds like aiming at creating «a large collection of identities involving addition, multiplication and division» — i.e. hopelessly unfocused (as in 'too broad').

Comment: Okay, that’s a good point. I kind of was hoping that there are 10 or so identities used all the time like the binomial theorems, the geometric series, triangle numbers, …. But that might be just a bottomless pit.

Comment: I mean, maybe you have something more focused in mind — but it's hard to guess from the OP and 1 example...

Comment: I added the question as I was going to state it – does this sound too broad to you?

Answer (score 1):

Big-list "threads" tend to suffer from limited visibility of answers. The layout of pages here is meant to emphasize 1-2 top answers, not 20 or more. So invariably, the bottom-dwelling answer get little attention: nobody wants to dig that far to vote, edit, flag or even read. Just look at the tail end of any big-list post with many answers.

I suggest to create an thematic *index* of such posts instead. I [did this](http://mathindex.wordpress.com/) for certain kinds of calculus exercises. Compiling such an index is a fair bit of work, but it is also a way to tidy up the site: duplicates become more apparent, and so do the topics that are yet to be addressed.

---

By the way: if you are interested in adding a page "Examples of homeomorphisms" (or other topics in topology) to [Math.SE Index](http://mathindex.wordpress.com/) site, drop me a message either here or in chat.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't sound like a good fit for the StackExchange model. I would suggest that you start a blog or a wiki of your own instead.